# How to calculate no of hours between two dates in hive

Tags: hive

Write a hive query on to print all the phone numbers whose call duration is more than 60 min based on start and end time. One sample record is as below like this i have so many records in file.

```
 Phonenumber|callednumber|start time         |endtime            |Flag 
 9686365100 |9490444451  |2016-09-21 14-20-20|2016-09-21 14-20-60|T
```

Comment: use this function unix_timestamp() .  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Answer (score 0):

As Mike said it is ...

Select (unix_timestamp(endtime) -  unix_timestamp(start time) ) /60  as HoursDiff